# See if the control in a validator has the required attribute

Tags: angular

I am building a custom template forms validation directive. Is it possible to tell if the control has a required attribute on the control?

Comment: I'm relatively positive that you didn't intend to ask a yes/no question, and probably meant to ask *how* to accomplish this task.  You may want to consider rewording your question, and adding some additional context to flesh out your actual requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can. Here is the code. Let's say if my form control name is 'firstName'.

```
<div *ngIf="firstName.dirty && firstName.errors" class="errorClass w-100">
     <div *ngIf="firstName.hasError('required')">
        display error message
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the example above we show an error message if the field is required and empty, the second condition is what you looking for.

```
<span class="error" *ngIf="email.invalid && !!email.errors.required && (email.dirty || email.touched)">Email is required.</span>
<form [formGroup]="subscribeForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="addSubscriber($event)">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email" formControlName="email"/>
    <button class="button margin-top-15" type="submit">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```